# Can't exclude subdirectory in python setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools

I have the following structure:

```
project
  - setup.py
  - app
    - stuff
    - to
    - include
    - module_to_exclude
      - more stuff
```

In `setup.py` I have:

```
setup(
    name="app",
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['module_to_exclude', '*.module_to_exclude', '*.module_to_exclude.*', 'module_to_exclude.*']),
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[...],
    ext_modules=[],
    package_data={},
)
```

But when I run:

`python setup.py bdist_wheel`

I can see that `module_to_exclude` is still being added. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

```
packages=find_packages(exclude=['app.module_to_exclude']),
```

`module_to_exclude` is a subpackage of `app`, not a top-level package.

Answer (score 2):

Extending the answer of @phd: If you want to exclude `module_to_exclude` **and** all submodules of it you would need to add:

```
packages=find_packages(exclude=['app.module_to_exclude', 'app.module_to_exclude.*'])
```